# Open a new Window minimized on OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, monomac

I'm porting a windows application to osx.

On Windows it is possible to create a new window minimized, this is used when the user has set it's state to "Do not disturb". This allows us to notify him "discretely" about a new message, since the window is displayed in the taskbar but it is not displayed on screen.

I have tried to do this using cocoa but the only way i managed to get a window displayed minimized is to minimize it after showing it. But this means that that the window is first shown and then is animated send to dock what in my opinion is quite ugly.

The question i have come to, is their a way to open a window a new window minimized in cocoa?

Comment: It's a user preference global to a user account to minimize windows to the Dock individually or to the app icon. If it's set to minimize to the app icon your design does not work. You should consider a different approach. You can badge the icon in the dock or change it. You can also use NSUserNotification. Lots of ways to arrive the goal if the goal is about the user experience and not rigidly about the window.